# Regarding infinite geometric series, how to derive the value for r.

Tags: sequences-and-series

This question will only require a simple explanation, however thus far I have not been able find this from my notes or the web.

The sum of an infinite series is:
$$a/(n)r$$

if the series is :$$1/(n)^2$$

then r = 1/2.

my question is
what is the derivation for $$n^2 == r = 1/2$$

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

EDIT:

The image below shows the question as it is written,

[image]

As shown it says r = 1/2, for clarity my question is why does r = 1/2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your equations mean or what notation you're using (by $a/(n)$ do you mean the $n$-th element of the sequence, i.e. $a_n$?), but I think there is at least one error.

If we have a geometric sequence (i.e. the next term is $r$ times the previous one):

$$a_{n+1} = ra_n$$

then we can find the infinite sum of the series:

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i = \frac{a_0}{1 - r}$$

But the sequence

$$
\left\{\frac{1}{1}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{9}, \dots \frac{1}{n^2}\right\}
$$

is not a geometric sequence; its terms don't differ by a constant factor. (For example, $\frac{1}{4}$ is $1/4$ times as big as $1$, but $\frac{1}{9}$ is **not** $1/4$ times as big as $\frac{1}{4}$).

So we can't use the previous formula to sum this series. (Footnote: However, this series does have a sum -- it turns out to be $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$).

Comment: Thank you for your response, this has definately helped. I have added an image to the original question,as you can see it says r = 1/2. It this this I am unsure about, could you please inform me where in the question has this 1/2 been derived from ?

Comment: A series $n^p$ converges iff $p < 1$. In this case it's $-2$, so the series does converge. These are called $p$-series: http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/SeriesTests/p-series.html. Your notes seem to be using $r$ to indicate the $\frac{1}{2}$ added inside the denominator, and then I think you confuse it with the $r$ from geometric series. (I remember doing that all the time). But $p \ne \frac{1}{2}$ -- that would be the series $\sqrt{n}$, which converges, but is not relevant here.